Is there a way to word wrap a choice field in a flow?
I have a screen flow on an Experience Cloud site that displays a choice field. On a mobile device, the values are cut off. Is there a way to word wrap the values?


Text input fields can't be text wrapped. It's part of the HTML specification. Use a Long Text Area instead.

Can you tell screen flow to treat a picklist choice field as Long Textarea?  I'm not at my desktop now so I can't test it.
